# Same size table no matter the resolution?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want a table that will retain its size on the screen regardless if the user zooms in or out. How can I do this using html/CSS?
I used this in my CSS body.

```
body {
    background: url(images/bg7.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    font-family : Verdana, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif, arial ;
    background-color: #C2A366;
    margin: -0.6% 0px 0px 50px;
}
```

I want the table to stay the same size, just like the background, how is this possible?

Comment: Can't be done with CSS. Requires JS.

Comment: I'm willing to hear a JS solution, I just prefer css and html

Comment: The Pragmatick, divs and tables behave differently. IMHO, it wouldn't be redundant to have a solution that works specifically for tables.

Comment: Did you try using percents? ex. `width: 50%; height: 50%;` I think that should resize on zoom